# How to populate table based on the condition of another table's column value in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am kinda new in django and I am stuck.

I am building and app to store equipment registry. I have done a model for equipment list and i have a status values as "available", "booked", "maintenance"

I also have a model for all equipment that are not available. not in my html in the "not available registry" i want to show only details of equipment in the list that are marked as "booked" and "maintenance"

Comment: can you show us your code ? otherwise think of `custom queryset manager` have a look at this tuto :https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/16/django-tip-11-custom-manager-with-chainable-querysets.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways of doing this.
To filter out objects of the model that are marked as "booked" or "maintenance" you can use [complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). It allows you to filter objects with `OR` statement. Here you need to find objects that have status set to "booked" OR to "maintenance". The query should look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Equipment.objects.filter(Q(status='booked') | Q(status='maintetnance'))
```

Second way of doing this is by using `__in` statement to filter objects that you need:

```
not_available_status = ['booked', 'maintenance']
Equipment.objects.filter(status__in=not_available_status)
```

And final way is to exclude objects that you don't need:

```
Equipment.objects.exclude(status='available')
```